# jQuery .append Onchange event firing multiple times

Tags: jquery

I have a form that should append some values into a "Notes" text area on change. I have several of these, and while some work just fine, others append the text 3 times. Here is an example  of the code that is firing multiple times:

HTML:

```
   <tr class="manufactured_div" title="Appraisal report must indicate there are no issues with the structural modifications or that the integrity of the seal of the home has not been compromised" >

    <td colspan="6">

        <b>Are there any structural modifications or additions?</b>

            <select class="table3_select" name="mfr_structural" id="mfr_structural">

                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>

            </select>    

      </td>

</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
    $('#mfr_structural').change(function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    var insert = '\n* MFR Structural Mods? : ' + text;
    $('#activity_summary').append(insert);
});
```

The .append happens twice when the document loads, and once when the value in the dropdown is changed. If it matters, the "manufactured_div" starts as hidden until a certain value is selected in a dropdown earlier in the form.

I have Googled this, and searched on SO, but everything I have found has not quite applied to my situation in some way. I have also found answers that refer to p tags not being closed, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. I have tried changing the jQuery from

```
.change(function()....
```

to

```
.on('change', function()...
```

but that didn't help either.

What I need to happen is the .append only fires if a selection is made in the dropdown. If the dropdown doesn't change, then I do not want it to append to the notes div.

Let me know if you need to see more of the code (there are some privacy issues that prevent me from showing too much or providing the URL), or if clarification is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: It should fire only selected option's changed which is right in your code.

Comment: I have about 20 of these in my form. Does that affect it at all?

Comment: `ID` must be unique.

Comment: I double checked them, and they are all unique.

Comment: OK, so I figured it out. Now, the question is how do I answer this question according to SO rules? Do I add a comment with the answer or do I actually post an answer and mark it as the answer?

Comment: BTW, it was a syntax error somewhere in the code NOT posted here, if that matters as to how I should handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're doing wrong since you didn't paste more code.  But click the button below to run my version of your code.  Does exactly what you want it to.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#mfr_structural').change(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    var insert = '\n* MFR Structural Mods? : ' + text;
    $('#activity_summary').append(insert);
    console.log(insert);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="manufactured_div" title="Appraisal report must indicate there are no issues with the structural modifications or that the integrity of the seal of the home has not been compromised">

  <td colspan="6">

    <b>Are there any structural modifications or additions?</b>

    <select class="table3_select" name="mfr_structural" id="mfr_structural">

      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>

    </select>

  </td>

</tr>
  </table>
<div id="activity_summary"></div>
```